# LINQ to XML how compare children with repeater items

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've got a print button that gives XML data to filling an adobe lifecycle template. I'm trying to compare ROWID in XML with a repeater rowid to make it print the information about the row the button was clicked on.

```
Int32 rownum = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
string xmlROWID = Xmld.Descendants("ROWID").First().Value;
```

Here are 2 of the children in the XML:

```
<VKRSADL>
    <CUSTOMER_SADLS>
      <TABLEVALUE>
        <ROW>
          <ROWID>0</ROWID>
          <ID>Съкредитополучател</ID>
          <TYPE>48</TYPE>
          <TYPEID>1</TYPEID>
          <TYPECODE>1</TYPECODE>
          <CRSCODE>777</CRSCODE>
          <EGN />
          <NAME />
          <XML>
            <SADL0>
              <OwnerCrsCode />
              <TABLEVALUE />
            </SADL0>
          </XML>
          <XMLCHECK />
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
          <ROWID>1</ROWID>
          <ID>Съкредитополучател</ID>
          <TYPE>48</TYPE>
          <TYPEID>2</TYPEID>
          <TYPECODE>1</TYPECODE>
          <CRSCODE>123123</CRSCODE>
          <EGN />
          <NAME />
          <XML>
            <SADL1>
              <OwnerCrsCode />
              <TABLEVALUE />
            </SADL1>
          </XML>
          <XMLCHECK />
        </ROW>
      </TABLEVALUE>
    </CUSTOMER_SADLS>
  </VKRSADL>
```

Comparing it to the First() gives me only the first ROWID, and there can be multiple. How can I compare the repeater rowid it to each of the ROWID's I've got saved?

I've tried this:

```
foreach (var child in Xmld.Root.Element("REQUEST").Element("VKRSADL").Element("CUSTOMER_SADLS").Element("TABLEVALUE").Elements("ROW").Elements()) {
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

but I get an error:
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_f2rvuyke.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]? Unless it's genuinely tied to ASP.NET, it would be good to remove that dependency, and just end up with a console application - and sample XML. (It's not really clear whether your issue is fetching the repeater IDs, or comparing those with the XML...)

Comment: I'll do that right now, I just thought it might be better to get a bit more indepth. Updated.

Comment: Well this isn't a [mcve] now - you've just got two lines of code and part of an XML doc. Again, please be as clear as you *possibly* can about what you're trying to do, and how you've tried to do it. (Yes, `First()` will only give you a single element - so why use it? What have you tried without `First()`?)

Comment: Also, it's not clear whether those "chunks" of XML are within parent elements (e.g. "ROW") or whether they're really peers with the same parent node.

Comment: Update again, I hope this clears it up.

Comment: That certainly helps on the XML side, although I suspect it includes more information than we actually need - presumably you only need to show one element with the ID and one with "something else you might want to fetch". No sign of what you've tried instead of `First()` though. Please read apiserving

Comment: In particular, is your question really "How can I find the ROW element with a ROWID child element with a specific value?"

Comment: I did try one more thing, updated the question once again with more info. I abandoned that approoach, because I couldn't get past the error.

I want to compare the ROWID to the repeater ROW and only go through if they match.

Comment: Well you should investigate why you're getting that error. What's returning null?

Comment: The whole line is returning null.

Comment: Well the line isn't returning *anything*. You need to work out why you're getting a `NullReferenceException`. We can't easily tell as we don't know what the full structure of the XML is (we can't see a REQUEST element, so we don't know whether that's genuinely a child of the root element, or whether it's actually the root element) but you shouldn't abandon something just because you're getting an exception you don't understand. You should investigate it to work out why you're getting the exception.

Comment: It was the actual root element, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your question, you want to iterate through `ROW` element to get all elements which their `ROWID` is equal to a certain value.

You can use below code to get all `ROW` elements, then you can do what ever you want with each `ROW`, in my example below I print `ROWID` to console window:

```
string xml = "<VKRSADL><CUSTOMER_SADLS><TABLEVALUE><ROW><ROWID>0</ROWID><ID>Съкредитополучател</ID><TYPE>48</TYPE><TYPEID>1</TYPEID><TYPECODE>1</TYPECODE><CRSCODE>777</CRSCODE><EGN /><NAME /><XML><SADL0><OwnerCrsCode /><TABLEVALUE /></SADL0></XML><XMLCHECK /></ROW><ROW><ROWID>1</ROWID><ID>Съкредитополучател</ID><TYPE>48</TYPE><TYPEID>2</TYPEID><TYPECODE>1</TYPECODE><CRSCODE>123123</CRSCODE><EGN /><NAME /><XML><SADL1><OwnerCrsCode /><TABLEVALUE /></SADL1></XML><XMLCHECK /></ROW></TABLEVALUE></CUSTOMER_SADLS></VKRSADL>";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

foreach (var child in xDoc.Element("VKRSADL").Element("CUSTOMER_SADLS").Element("TABLEVALUE").Elements().Where(e => e.Name == "ROW"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(child.Element("ROWID").Value);
}
```

Note: Above example assume that the XML schema will not be changed, and if it changed then an exception could be occurred.

Comment: I found this to be the best way to get the result I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants("ROW").Select(x => new {
                rowID = (int)x.Element("ROWID"),
                id = (string)x.Element("ID"),
                type = (int)x.Element("TYPE"),
                typeID = (int)x.Element("TYPEID"),
                typeCode = (int)x.Element("TYPECODE"),
                crsCode = (int)x.Element("CRSCODE"),
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```